# Understand this rewrite rules so I can change it safelly?

Tags: .htaccess

```
# -FrontPage-

#<Limit GET POST>
#   order deny,allow
#   deny from all
#   allow from all
#</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Limit>

AuthUserFile /home1/tenleiye/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home1/tenleiye/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp

# Use PHP5 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
AuthName tenleiyen.com
#IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Force www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tenleiyen\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.tenleiyen.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

    # Do not change or site will be f*ked. Restrict all except the list below, redirecting all traffic to the index.php
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|1\.ico|favicon\.png|apple-touch-icon(.*)|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt|css|js|images|uploads|videos|download|sitemap\.xml)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have a lovely note by previous programmer expressing i cannot change the permissions. If I add something or even remove a snippet from the `RewriteCond` it will 404.

I cannot:

1. use the root directory,
2. get a `sitemap.xml` to be read,
3. drop a `1.jpg` file in the root directory and see it,
4. drop my webmaster tools `.html` file into the root directory to be read.

Everything is going to the index.php file and all I can do is use the folders specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tenleiyen\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.tenleiyen.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

At this rule, the condition verify if your domain starts with `tenleiyen.com`, if so, it will rewrite the request to `http://www.tenleiyen.com/$1`.

The $1 stands for the value held at `^(.*)$` which basically means anything after the domain, for example `http://www.tenleiyen.com/index.php`.

The 2 flags at the end means permanent redirect aka 301 redirect and L stand for LAST as in last rule.

---

This one is slight complicated so I will go by parts:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|1\.ico|favicon\.png|apple-touch-icon(.*)|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt|css|js|images|uploads|videos|download|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The `$1` is whatever you capture first in the next `RewriteRule` in this case `^(.*)$` which is anything after the domain not counting the initial `/` see image below (more specifically follow the green line):

[image: back-reference]

So basically the right hand of the condition compares if the left hand start with any of those keywords:

- index.php OR
- 1.ico OR
- favicon.png OR
- apple-touch-icon(anything else after) OR
- crossdomain.xml OR
- robots.txt OR
- css OR
- js OR
- images OR
- uploads OR
- videos OR
- download OR
- sitemap.xml

If it does not start with any of it then it will redirect it to the `index.php`.

If it matches with any of the above mentioned then it will give you direct access.

You will be able to access:

```
http://yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml
```

But won't be able to access

```
http://yourdomain.com/test/sitemap.xml
```

---

**Now this is what I believe that you want:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The above rule will verify if a file, directory or symbolic link exists if it does then it will not redirect to the index.php if it doesn't then it will redirect to the `index.php`.

Comment: I overwrote everything under RewriteEngine On with what you gave me and it worked perfectly. Can someone give me a link of a video tutorial or such so i can learn what this stuff does.

Comment: I know it takes time to answer questions so I would be more than happy to compensate you for your time for helping me via pp..

Comment: @Sparxx you can read the documents at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html I don't think there is a video tutorial that covers all the good stuff such as the back reference for instance while the documents does cover it and a lot more.